# how to install phonegap "push plugin" in ionic project(android)?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I am new to ionic framework, I am working on push notification in my android ionic project using phone gap push plugin referring the following documentation [phonegap push plugin link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

But I am unable to find how it gets worked. I need to send notifications to all the devices who already install as a gesture of revisit of my app.
Can any one give clear description step by step to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install plugin from `http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/` 
create one project on google Api console (https://console.developers.google.com/
).

There is method of Registration where you will get     `$cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {console.log(result);`

you will get device token. Register that device token and save that token on created project from Google API.

Comment: thanks for reply,where we need to add the register() function?

Comment: in device ready ., Read http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/  full document first,

Comment: yeah! thanks! by referring through ionic push docs i made it working in android.

Comment: Cool . Upvote my answer too .and that shared link will redirect to my login screen :)